# My loop is not performing as I expect it to

Tags: assembly, x86, strcat

I am running a C program that calls an external assembly function. For academic purposes, I am trying to perform `strcat`. I pass the two strings to my assembly program as char * parameters. I push ebp to the stack and assign string1 and string2 to edx and ebx like so:

```
mov edx, [ebp+8]
mov ebx, [ebp+4]
```

Now the rest is as follows:

```
procStr1:
     cmp BYTE PTR [edx], 0
     jne readStr1
procStr2:
     cmp BYTE PTR [ebx], 0
     jne readStr2
     jmp bottom
readStr1:
    inc edx
    jmp procStr1
readStr2:
    mov BYTE PTR [edx], 'a'
    inc edx
    inc ebx
    jmp procStr2

bottom:
    inc edx
    mov BYTE PTR [edx], 0
    pop ebx
    pop edx
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I am simply testing to see if it works by adding a's to the end of string1. If I enter 'hi' and 'bye' I expect to get hiaaa printed out by the C program (by printing out string1). Instead I get usually 13 a's after string1, no matter how big string2 is. I would appreciate any input, it is really boggling my mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do a:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

at the top?

If so, your arguments are now found at:

```
mov edx, [ebp+8]
mov ebx, [ebp+Ch]  ; 0xC, not 4 -- C-language passes args right-to-left
```

Also,

```
bottom:
    inc edx       ; This inc should be removed -- edx already points one
                  ; byte beyond the ultimate copied byte.
    mov BYTE PTR [edx], 0
```

Comment: +1 the data processing looks fine (except for that `inc edx`) so I suspect it's only a matter of getting those pointers from the correct location

Comment: I don't quite understand, I'm getting a syntax error when I do [ebp+C] when compiling in Visual Studio. And by right-to-left do you mean that the 2nd parameter is pushed onto the stack first?

Comment: I edited the post - C is in hexadecimal, so either use 12 (value of hex C), or append an h.  The idea is correct, just a syntax error.  As for right-to-left, yes I mean the 2nd parameter is pushed before the 1st parameter.  That's the C calling convention, it allows for variable numbers of arguments.

Comment: Yay!  I'm glad.  Welcome to the wonderful world of knowing how the machine works.  :)